# Best "pass" command in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I need a statement that does nothing.

What's the most readable and reliable one to use?

Is it `;`? Are there better alternatives?

I intend to use it in, among others, the following way:

```
if(skip)
  ;
else if(foo)
  foo();
else
  bar();
```

Will this have any unintended effects?

Comment: Why not just use `if( !skip ) { ... }`?

Comment: @Sirko: Sometimes, if you have a lot of conditions, it can be clearer to spell out the no-op cases rather than bundling their inverse into aggregate `else` conditions.

Answer (score 4):

What about `{}` - the empty block? That does ''nothing''.

```
if(skip) {
    //if I had the use case - I could help more.        
} else if(foo) {
  foo();
} else {
  bar();
}
```

In general, using ifs without `{}` brackets that are not one line is *usually* considered bad practice in JavaScript and most linters will complain about it.

Because using brackets is a lot more common than not using them - **the most readable alternative is to use brackets** since developers who are used to brackets (most of them) won't have to go through the cognitive load of understanding new syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If I was facing such problem I would better add a comment in the empty line, e.g.

```
if (skip) {
    /* We shouldn't do anything here */
} else if (foo) {
    foo();
} else {
    bar();
}
```

... and of course surround the blocks with brackets for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the if statement slightly?

```
if (skip === false) {
  if (foo) {
    foo();
  } else {
    bar();
  }
}
```

Comment: The opposite of `if (skip)` is `if (!skip)`, not `if (skip === false)`.

Comment: @seanxe now change `skip` to `1` (screw weak typing).

Comment: @Shai yeah i know about javascript's excellent type casting. i assumed skip would be a boolean from the OP.